# Validation Error on nested Embedded Documents in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm creating nested Embedded documents with two levels(Embedded Document inside Embedded Document)

Here's the code:

```
from mongoengine import *

class CommentDetails(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    category = StringField()

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(CommentDetails))

class Page(Document):
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))

comment1 = Comment(content='Good work!',comments=CommentDetails(name='John',category='fashion'))
comment2 = Comment(content='Nice article!',comments=CommentDetails(name='Mike',category='tech'))

page = Page(comments=[comment1, comment2])
page.save()
```

It gives following error on running:

> ValidationError: ValidationError (Page:None) (comments.Only lists and tuples may be used in a list field >1.comments.Only lists and tuples may be used in a list field: ['comments'])

I tried with single nested document and it works,also If I don't use EmbeddedDocuments for list it works. but not sure why it is not working for multiple levels of list of Embedded Documents .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from these 2 lines:

```
comment1 = Comment(content='Good work!',comments=CommentDetails(name='John',category='fashion'))
comment2 = Comment(content='Nice article!',comments=CommentDetails(name='Mike',category='tech'))
```

`comments` should be a list but you provide an object.

Use this:

```
comment1 = Comment(content='Good work!',comments=[CommentDetails(name='John',category='fashion')])
comment2 = Comment(content='Nice article!',comments=[CommentDetails(name='Mike',category='tech')])
```

Comment: Oh! Got it now. It should've been a list because it is a List Field. Thanks :)